# Is there a case scenario where routing thru AngularJS and thru ExpressJS are both required?

Tags: angularjs, express, socket.io

Routing functionality is defined in both ExpressJS thru `app.get('/*')` and in AngularJS thru

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/*
```

What is the case scenario for needing to define routes thru both?

Part 2.

Server and Client Communication in AngularJS takes place thru REST API ? ( can it be handled thru socket.io?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1

Angular is only on the front end, so if you need to make calls to your database (getting data or posting data), it'll likely go through a route that the backend (Express) created (app.get, app.post).

If all your data is coming from someone else's site (API) and you don't need to store anything, then in that case you might not need any routes on the back end.

It really depends on what you're building. If I build a 'to do' list, I can have a 'Tasks' and 'Completed Tasks' page using Angular routes and then post and get routes in ExpressJS. You can also have multiple SPA (single page applications) on Express in turn you may need another Angular module that will have it's own routes.

Comment: what do u mean by someone else's site?

Comment: Large sites often give access to some of their data through an API query that returns JSON. For example if you use www.reddit.com/hot.json you will get back JSON data that you can play with in Angular without having a backend. You can display it but you can't store it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your Part 2.

[AngularJS using SocketIO](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/)

AngularJS is an SPA (Single Page Application) framework. For SPAs which need pages to be loaded can be used to route thru Angular so

```
when('SPA1/...
```

to define particular SPA which may be subset of your total app can be routed thru Angular. Where as your regular routes `app.get('/home ...` can be done thru ExpressJS.